# can't `xkill` a "Loading…" bubble/growlbox

Tags: notification, xkill

I have no idea what program caused this "Loading..." growl notification / bubble / shoutbox / popup

[image: browser]

but it is still there outside of the web browser. (Even though it looks like a Javascript / web-browsy gif.)

[image: desktop]

I cannot `xkill` it. Is there another program I can use to identify elements that are drawn on the screen, and perhaps what `pid` to kill?

Comment: First of all, minimize the number of windows, just try closing them all. Then see if this is a browser problem with `killall firefox` or `killall chromium` , whichever you use

Comment: @Serg It does not go away if I minimise the windows.

Comment: I meant "minimize" as "decrease", not actually minimize. In other words close , the windows.